# How to convert numberic vector to character making every character element to have the same decimal length in R?

Tags: r

Consider I have a vector with its first elements being

```
c(6,6.5,6.25).
```

Is there a easy way to convert it to character in a way each character element has the same decimal length? This would achieve the following vector

```
c("6.00", "6.50", "6.25")
```

Comment: `format(c(6,6.5,6.25), digits = 3)`?

Comment: Oh, I have tried this only with format(6, digits = 3), which hans't work. With the other numbers it did. Thanks

Comment: Another method: `sprintf("%.2f",c(6,6.5,6.25))`.